# rebalancing access lists for better memory efficiency

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, acl

If I have R roles and I grant ALLOW access to a resource S to R-1 roles. As the roles get populated, it becomes clear that it would be a lot more efficient to grant DENY on the role that doesn't have access to S simply because it would reduce the amount of records stored in the database by X percent.

Is there a smart lib (in any language), paper, data structure, or even vocabulary related to these types of problems that would help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two papers on the subject are [this one](https://www.cse.msu.edu/~alexliu/publications/FirewallCompressor/FirewallCompressor_TPDS.pdf) which is then followed a couple years later by [this one](http://www.cse.msu.edu/~dalyjame/papers/DiplomatInfocom2013.pdf).  If you contacted the [professor heading the research](https://www.cse.msu.edu/~alexliu/) (or [the other professor on the papers](http://www.cse.msu.edu/~torng/)) then you might be able to get some code, but it doesn't appear that they've published any software.

Aside from that, you could model the problem using sets, but I'm unsure of how difficult it is to automatically simplify a system of sets - I don't know of a good set simplification library and wasn't able to find one with a few seconds of googling.  You could also model the problem using first order logic, but then you're probably getting into the realm of undecidability.